# Shisha Ushmonim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred eighty-six?

### ?ששה ושמונים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 286.

In casting about for a lazy gematria for this one, a lot seemed more appropriate for a different time on the calendar.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred eighty-five entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

286 years from G-d telling Avraham "lech l'cha", until Yosef's histalkus (passing). [Source](http://www.ou.org/torah/tt/5762/vayechi62/featuretidbit.htm).

Comment: interesting fact, but what is the significance of it?

Comment: @morahhochman absolutely none that I can tell. I don't think significance is the only requirement. The question says *"please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 286."*. I find this interesting, even if there is no significance.

Answer (score 1):

Gimtariot:

Abrabanel

BeMaamad Sinai

Hesed HaBore

Meah Peamim

Sod Amok

Sod HaAr"i

Atzei Ola